# how to stop timer if below or equal to 0 corona sdk

Tags: timer, lua, coronasdk, countdowntimer

I used this code by Rob Miracle from GitHub. It works fine but my problem is that whenever it reaches 00:00 or negative, it follows my instruction to go to another scene but it is still updating.

```
local secondsLeft = 2 * 60   -- 2 minutes * 60 seconds

local clockText = display.newText("02:00", 280, 1, native.systemFontBold, 25)
clockText:setFillColor( 1, 0, 0 )

local function updateTime()
    -- decrement the number of seconds
    secondsLeft = secondsLeft - 1

    -- time is tracked in seconds.  We need to convert it to minutes and seconds
    local minutes = math.floor( secondsLeft / 60 )
    local seconds = secondsLeft % 60

    -- make it a string using string format.  
    local timeDisplay = string.format( "%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds )
    clockText.text = timeDisplay
end

-- run them timer
local countDownTimer = timer.performWithDelay( 1000, updateTime, secondsLeft )
```

Comment: What is still updating? Your question is unclear.

Comment: I added this code:                                                                                     if timeDisplay <= "00:00" then
   print "Game Over"
   GameOver()
  end                                                                                                  I tried to track the time, but wen it goes to the function game over, it is still decrementing.

Comment: I check your code. It works fine. Text object don't update after it reached "00:00" time.

Comment: sir @David Bowling, I added this code "print (secondsLeft)" before secondsLeft = secondsLeft - 1.   And when I go to another scene it is still decrementing at the corona simulator output. That's why I get errors when it reaches 1 :(

Comment: I'm confused. Yesterday you said that adding `timer.cancel()` worked. Are you now saying that by adding `print (secondsLeft)` before `secondsLeft = secondsLeft - 1` in the function `updateTime()`, this no longer works? BTW, place backticks (\`) around inline code for readability.

Comment: Yes, yesterday I ignored the error because it seems it stops, but a while ago I noticed that every time I get the error, it's always after 2 minutes so i keep track again the function and then I notice that it actually doesn't stops.

Comment: 1) What are these errors? 2) You need to add actual code to your question in an Edit or Update section. Include the code where the error occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need to call the [`timer.cancel()`](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/timer/cancel.html) function. Try forward-declaring `countDownTimer` so that you can use it in `updateTime()`:

```
local countDownTimer

...

local function updateTime()
...

   if timeDisplay <= "00:00" then
      timer.cancel(countDownTimer)
      print "Game Over"
      GameOver()
   end

...
end

countDownTimer = timer.performWithDelay( 1000, updateTime, secondsLeft )
```

Comment: oh sorry, I forgot to delete the 'local' in countdowntimer, It worked sir! :) Thank You :)